# It's secure to update the CSRF token on every request passed as the response? (AJAX)

Tags: csrf

I was thinking on how to implement CSRF tokens to our web application. I know how to do it with a simple HTTP `POST`. Our problems comes when we talk about AJAX, I know I've to attach the token to our request but... I should then update with a new token.

This will only happens when the request it's valid, so if it's valid it will return a new CSRF token as part of the data returned in JSON.

It's that correct? Or there is a better way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do it that way you run the risk of having a lot of failing requests, depending on your application. For example, if a user has your site open in multiple tabs.

I would recommend keeping the CSRF token the same for some period of time, much like you would a session token. It's not necessary to change it with every request.